# Combining two text files based the second field in the first text file only when also present in the second text file

Tags: linux, bash, text-files

I have two text files that I would like to somehow combine yet substitute based on the second field in the first file.  Below is the format of the first file.  Which is words with their count from a corpus.

file_1.txt

```
1000 the
999 been
950 phone
850 ball
800 watch
799 porch
```

File 2 is some of the words that can be found in the first file but have a breakdown of that word from the second field on.

file_2.txt

```
the th e
been be en
shirt sh ir t
phone pho ne
desk d esk
chair cha i r
watch wa t c h
floor f loo r
```

What I would like to get is below.  When the word(s) are present in both files I like to only have the word break down from the second file.

file_3.txt

```
1000 th e
999 be en
950 pho ne
850 ball
800 wa t c h
799 porch
```

I've been trying to do some `sort` stuff between the two files based on the fields but I'm pretty lost.

Comment: With `join`, `sort`, `sed`, `awk` and `bash`: `join -t _ -1 2 -2 1 -a 1 <(sed 's/ /_/' file_1.txt | sort -t _ -k 2,2) <(sed 's/ /_/' file_2.txt | sort -t _ -k 1,1) -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 | sed 's/_$//' | awk -F _ '{print $1,$NF}' | sort -nr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Awk:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { m[$2]=$1 } FNR != NR && $1 in m { w=$1; $1=""; print m[w] $0}' file_1.txt file_2.txt
```

That is:

- For each line in the first file, build a map of `word -> id`
- For each line in the second file:

  - Save the first field (the word) in a variable
  - Clear the first field
  - Print the id using the map and the word, and the rest of the line